# Stop adjacent command blocks from activating?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've got a setup where two independent command blocks must be placed next to each other. How can I stop both of them from triggering? Shown below is a minimal example.

[image]

Comment: Why do they need to be next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the second is activating is due to the properties of redstone to power the block it's pointing to.

To prevent the second command from powering, move the wire one block away from the command block (to the current position of the redstone block in the example) and move the redstone block 1 block in the same direction. Then but a solid block where the wire **used to be**. This will power only the command block behind the solid block.

This will not work if the wire is not pointing at the solid block. To fix this, replace the wire with a repeater facing the solid block.